# How to represent microbuses (hail and ride transport) in GTFS

Tags: transport, gtfs

I am doing transit database for my city in GTFS format. And I have an problem with microbuses (hail-and-ride transport), because this transport doesn't have stops. As a workaround, I can made stops every 100-200 meters, but maybe it's possible to do easier. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an open question, and there is a working group that has hashed out some ideas about how to represent them: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gtfs-flexible-wg

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it